# Transform multidim array to single dim array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a json of player attendance to excel using `json2xls`. It's adding each json entry as a row in the created excel file but what I wanted to achieve is that each player should only have 1 row and the time entries will become new columns.

```
    [
    {
      username: 'player1',
      nickname: 'Player One',
      capturetime: '23:4',
      ismuted: false,
      isdeafened: false,
      ispresent: true,
    },
    {
      username: 'player1',
      nickname: 'Player One',
      capturetime: '23:5',
      ismuted: false,
      isdeafened: false,
      ispresent: false,
    },
    {
      username: 'player1',
      nickname: 'Player One',
      capturetime: '23:31',
      ismuted: false,
      isdeafened: false,
      ispresent: false,
    },
    {
      username: 'player1',
      nickname: 'Player One',
      capturetime: '7:27',
      ismuted: false,
      isdeafened: false,
      ispresent: false,
    }
  ]
```

I found out that to achieve this. I need to transform the json to the one similar below. How can I transform the json to look like this?

```
[{
    username: 'player1',
    nickname: 'Player One',
    capturetime1: '23:4',
    ispresent1: true,
    ismuted1: false,
    isdeafened1: false
    capturetime2: '23:5',
    ispresent2: false,
    ismuted2: false,
    isdeafened2: false
    capturetime3: '23:31',
    ispresent3: false,
    ismuted3: false,
    isdeafened3: false
    capturetime4: '7:27',
    ispresent4: false,
    ismuted4: false,
    isdeafened4: false
}]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `flatten()` on the players' objects?

Comment: Now that I look at your shape - That's a *weird* way to structure the data IMO. I'm not sure how you are gonna accomplish that.

Comment: I second Joel. The expected result is a very unusable structure. Almost always, you want arrays rather than `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`.

Comment: You can iterate over those objects using `Object.entries()` and you get access to the item, as well as the index itself. That way, you can iterate without destabilizing the structure the way you're intending.

Comment: `Object.entries(players).map((item, i) => [your code goes here])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not the structure is desirable, what you need to get there is a reduce on the source array iterating the keys of each object...

```js
const array = [{
    username: 'player1',
    nickname: 'Player One',
    capturetime: '23:4',
    ismuted: false,
    isdeafened: false,
    ispresent: true,
  },
  {
    username: 'player1',
    nickname: 'Player One',
    capturetime: '23:5',
    ismuted: false,
    isdeafened: false,
    ispresent: false,
  },
  {
    username: 'player1',
    nickname: 'Player One',
    capturetime: '23:31',
    ismuted: false,
    isdeafened: false,
    ispresent: false,
  },
  {
    username: 'player1',
    nickname: 'Player One',
    capturetime: '7:27',
    ismuted: false,
    isdeafened: false,
    ispresent: false,
  }
]
const result = array.reduce((acc, el, i) => {
  for (let k of Object.keys(el)) {
    let key = k === 'username' || k === 'nickname' ? k : k+(i+1)
    acc[key] = el[k];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

**EDIT** if a compounded object per player is desired, then the above logic can be applied individually to unique players (presuming uniqueness is determined by username)...

```js
const array = [{
    username: 'player1',
    nickname: 'Player One',
    capturetime: '23:4',
    ismuted: false,
    isdeafened: false,
    ispresent: true,
  },
  {
    username: 'player1',
    nickname: 'Player One',
    capturetime: '23:5',
    ismuted: false,
    isdeafened: false,
    ispresent: false,
  },
  {
    username: 'player2',
    nickname: 'Player Twp',
    capturetime: '23:31',
    ismuted: false,
    isdeafened: false,
    ispresent: false,
  },
  {
    username: 'player2',
    nickname: 'Player Two',
    capturetime: '7:27',
    ismuted: false,
    isdeafened: false,
    ispresent: false,
  }
]

// here, the logic from the prior edit, packaged as a function
function objectFromPlayers(players) {
  return players.reduce((acc, el, i) => {
    for (let k of Object.keys(el)) {
      let key = k === 'username' || k === 'nickname' ? k : k + (i + 1)
      acc[key] = el[k];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

// first reduce into unique players
function groupByPlayer(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, player) => {
    let username = player.username;
    if (!acc[username]) acc[username] = [];
    acc[username].push(player)
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const groupedPlayers = Object.values(groupByPlayer(array));
// now groupedPlayers is an array of array of unique players
// map the original logic over it
const result = groupedPlayers.map(objectFromPlayers);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however if I have other players data it will compile json to a single json. Can it be that if a new player entry is detected, it will create a new set?

Comment: @kams - edited to demonstrate handling distinct identifying keys.  First group them by username (or whatever the unique key is), then apply the logic I've already suggested to those groups.